# The mystery of Crawling Rules

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, crawling

The requirements:
exclude any subfolders in a document library on search results.

Crawling Rules set up in the following order:

1. `https://MySite.*(/.+)*/.*[.].*` use regexp checked Include all item in this path checked
2. `https://MySite.*/.*(/.+)*` use regexp checked exclude All items in this path checked

After a Index reset and then a full crawl, I could see the in the Crawling log, only 1 item `https://MySite.xxx.com` is listed as successfully crawled.

All tests done on the Crawling Rules page was as expected. so:

- `https://mysite/doclib` will not be crawled.
- `https://mysite.xxx.com/doclib1/subfolder` will be not be crawled.
- `https://mysite.xxx.com/doclib1/subfolder/doc.doc` Will be crawled.

But why none of the actual documents or files are not crawled at all?

I have seen a lot of posts regarding use the technique, so the include for the specific type of item first then the excluding rule for the rest of the paths.

What have I done wrong here? or is it a https issue I wonder?

Comment: To clarify, if you remove those crawl rules then crawling works successfully and the entire site is crawled?

Comment: Yes. And if I just remove the 2nd one and without reset index. Then after a full crawl then a lot of items deleted with the message "Deleted by the gatherer ( This item was deleted because its parent was deleted. )"